# I need advice on Go integration testing using Postgres db in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, integration-testing

I am very new to Go world. I have some db functions that I need to test.
So first I have a database.go file that connects to a postgres db:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "os"
)

var DB *gorm.DB
var err error

func Open() error {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable", os.Getenv("HOST"), os.Getenv("USER"),
        os.Getenv("PASSWORD"), os.Getenv("DB"), os.Getenv("PORT"))
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Then I have a customers.go file with functions that interact with that db:

```
import (
    "customers/cmd/database"
    "time"
)

type Customers struct {
    ID           int       
    CustomerName string   
    Active       bool      
    Balance      float32   
    ActiveSince  time.Time
}

func Get(id int) (Customers, error) {
    var customer Customers
    result := database.DB.First(&customer, id)

    if result.Error != nil {
        return Customers{}, result.Error
    } else {
        return customer, nil
    }
}
```

This is all running in docker, there is customers container and postgres container. Now the question is how do I test my `Get(id int)` function? I was researching dockertest but that spins up a different db and my Get function uses the one I specified in database.go. So is there a standard Go way to test these functions?

Answer (score 0):

it is a docker net problem but golang:

1. you can create a docker net, run both container in one net.[doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/)
   or use network `--network=host`
2. export postgres container's port to localhost, and customers container link to localhost,`-pxx:xx`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Postgres port is already exposed to localhost, I can connect to it through my host machine. What is customers container link for?

Comment: customers container link to your localhost's ip 

Answer (score 0):

there is standard way of unit tesing in go. pl refer [testing](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) and [testify/assert](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert). Unit tests are typically written in xxx_test.go file next to the code.

coming to unit testing of db access layer code, one option would be to have a testenv helper and use it on these lines.

customers_test.go:

```golang
package dbaccess

import "testing"

func TestDbAccessLayer(t *testing.T) {
  testEnv := testUtils.NewTestEnv()
  // testEnv should do the required initialization e.g. 
  // start any mocked services, connection to database, global logger etc.
  if err := testEnv.Start(); err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
  }
  // at the end of the test, stop need to reset state
  // e.g. clear any entries created by test in db
  defer testEnv.Stop()

  // add test code
  // add required assertion to validate 
}
```

have a separate `docker-compose.yml` file and use it with `docker compose` command to start/stop services like `postgresdb`.

`go test` command may be used to run the tests. refer to the command docs for details.

Comment: ok, so I am not sure I understand what this testenv is going to do. My Get() method uses DB variable assigned in database.go. That DB instance contains host and port that are different if you connect from outside the customers docker container

Comment: based on how ur localenv is setup for testing, u may want to use `go test` on host or execute the script inside a container.

Comment: Nothing is set up for testing yet. These are the first tests I have